# Selecting the most accurate data available in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have addresses and pricing data in my database. The pricing data is not complete, usually it applies to a region, other times to specific addresses. I have a plpgsql function that should retrieve the most accurate pricing data available. I currently have this in my function:

```
SELECT price_est.sau_price_avg INTO _est_price FROM price_est WHERE price_est.neighbourhood_id = _neighbourhood_id AND  --neighbourhood level
                                                                    price_est.district_id = _district_id AND
                                                                    price_est.municipality_id = _municipality_id AND
                                                                    price_est.county_id = _county_id;
IF _est_price IS NULL THEN
    SELECT price_est.sau_price_avg INTO _est_price FROM price_est WHERE price_est.neighbourhood_id IS NULL AND          --district level
                                                                        price_est.district_id = _district_id AND
                                                                        price_est.municipality_id = _municipality_id AND
                                                                        price_est.county_id = _county_id;
END IF;
...
```

If data is unavailable somewhere then there are no foreign key references to that region.

This seems like a very clumsy solution to me. Is there a better way to do this?

I can make changes to tables and data presentation is necessary.

----------------------------------- edit -----------------------------------

I made Nick Barnes-s answer work for me like this:

```
SELECT price_est.sau_price_avg
FROM price_est
WHERE
    (price_est.county_id = _county_id OR price_est.county_id IS NULL) AND
    (price_est.municipality_id = _municipality_id OR price_est.municipality_id IS NULL) AND
    (price_est.district_id = _district_id OR price_est.district_id IS NULL) AND
    (price_est.neighbourhood_id = _neighbourhood_id OR price_est.neighbourhood_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY price_est.neighbourhood_id NULLS LAST,
         price_est.district_id NULLS LAST,
         price_est.municipality_id NULLS LAST,
         price_est.county_id NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select them both at the same time, and use an `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT` to prioritise in order of accuracy:

```
SELECT price_est.sau_price_avg
INTO _est_price
FROM price_est
WHERE
  (price_est.neighbourhood_id = _neighbourhood_id OR price_est.neighbourhood_id IS NULL) AND
  price_est.district_id = _district_id AND
  price_est.municipality_id = _municipality_id AND
  price_est.county_id = _county_id
ORDER BY price_est.neighbourhood_id NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that `NULLS LAST` is the default ordering, so it's not strictly necessary, but it's good to make your intentions clear in a case like this.